# MySQL Query not returning

Tags: mysql

I'm unfamiliar with MySQL, and I don't know where to begin with solving this query issue.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `rmedspa`.`clients` c  
inner join `rmedspa`.`tickets` t on c.clientid = t.clientid  
where c.fldclass is not null     
AND t.ticketID > 0
```

This query returns just fine in MySQL Workbench, in 30 seconds, and the IDE is limiting the query results to 1000 records.  The database is not on my own machine, but on a server that is in a different location (in other words, it's going out to the internet and it's slow).  If I add an order by at the end, the query never returns.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `rmedspa`.`clients` c  
inner join `rmedspa`.`tickets` t on c.clientid = t.clientid  
where c.fldclass is not null     
AND t.ticketID > 0
ORDER BY t.ticketid
```

There are "many" tickets for 1 client.  t.ticketid is an int.  clientid is an int, too.

I don't know where to begin to find out why the ORDER BY is causing this query to never return.  It doesn't fail, it just doesn't return.

Comment: Run `SHOW PROCESSLIST` in another window and you'll see what the query is doing. It's probably sorting very, very slowly because the result set doesn't fit in available memory so it's paging on and off disk.

Comment: The answer to this question will depend on a lot of factors.  The most important is the actual size of the resultset.  If it's millions of rows, you could be overflowing the server's sorting capabilities.  What do you get if you substitute `count(*)` instead of `*` in the select clause?

Comment: Where do I run this?  I ask because I tried to make a new query in MySQL Workbench (can you tell I'm a SQL Server guy with my terminology) and I can't actually execute SHOW PROCESSLIST.

Comment: Count(*) doesn't return, either.  There are only 129k records in the tickets table, and 3000 in the clients table.  Ugh.  I don't have the ability to alter this database at all, I'm just trying to pull tickets from it -- I want to pull all 129k right now, and every night only the new ones.  Which is why I need ORDER BY because I can't pull all the records at once, I need to pull 100 at a time as I work through them.

Comment: If you open two windows of MySQL workbench, and, in one window, run your problem slow to forever running query, and, in the other window, run `SHOW PROCESSLIST` as @Dan Grossman says, you will see your query executing.

Comment: Thank you vpit3833.  That worked great.  Not sure what I'm looking at yet, but your comment was spot on.

Comment: How long are the `clients` and `tickets` rows? Do any contain large LOBs?  You will get 129k rows back, each of which contains the concatenation of both rows.  Note also that ORDER BY is not how you would partition the data.  To partition efficiently you need to use an indexed column, such as clientid, and a filtering clause such as `where clientid between x and y`.

Comment: Jim, that was it.  I didn't realize that doing an ORDER BY wasn't helping to limit the result set.  Once I changed my query to use "ticketid > 0 and ticketid <= 100", the query returned in no time.  Thanks so much.  Put that in an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: With 129K records, it would be better if you posted the tables'definitions (so we can check existing indices).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Post is a short review of previous comments plus some hints on SQL-Query for you.

**Query building**

- Whenever the column names of a join condition match, you can rewrite the join statement as follows:
  `INNER JOIN {database}.{table} t USING({joinColumn})`
- Check your indexes - in your case: Are the columns of the join condition and the where statement indexed?

**mySQL result**

- The ORDER BY statement often requires a reordering of the result set in memory. If you expected large results (many rows) and/or large rows (many columns) but see no result the mySQL Server is not properly configured for that case - [How MySQL Uses Memory](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/memory-use.html), [Optimizing Queries with EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-explain.html)